# В каком падеже употребить?

Tags: падежи, управление

Добрый вечер! Вопрос такой:

В каком падеже необходимо употребить словосочетание "эстетическая стоматология" после тире в данном предложении: *"Иванов с сотрудниками совершенствует и продвигает ещё одно приоритетное направление специальности – эстетическАЯ стоматологИЯ"?*

Если считать, что главное слово "продвигает", то задаем вопрос - продвигает что? эстетическую стоматологию. Если главное слово - направление, то вопрос: направление чего? - эстетической стоматологии.
Так как все-таки правильно задать вопрос? 
Иванов с сотрудниками совершенствует и продвигает ещё одно приоритетное направление специальности – эстетическую стоматологию.
Иванов с сотрудниками совершенствует и продвигает ещё одно приоритетное направление специальности – эстетической стоматологии.

Comment: Так а по смыслу "эстетическая стоматология" - это направление или специальность?

Answer (score 3):

Если "эстетическая стоматология" – это **направление**, тогда правильно будет:

> Иванов с сотрудниками совершенствует и продвигает ещё одно приоритетное направление специальности – эстетическую стоматологию.

При этом подразумевается, что выше речь шла о некой специальности, и данное предложение дополняет начатую тему (без контекста это непонятно, к сожалению).

Если же "эстетическая стоматология" – это **специальность**, тогда можно написать

> Иванов с сотрудниками совершенствует и продвигает ещё одно приоритетное направление специальности "эстетическая стоматология".

Только так, без тире.

Если же "направление" и "специальность" в данном контексте значат одно и то же, тогда никакого "направления специальности" не может быть, фразу нужно построить иначе.

Comment: У Вас во втором примере получилось, что специальность "эстетическая стоматология" имеет не одно приоритетное направление, его-то ("ещё одно") и продвигает Иванов с сотрудниками. )))

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova у автора же именно так во втором примере: "Иванов с сотрудниками совершенствует и продвигает ещё одно приоритетное направление специальности – эстетической стоматологии".

Comment: А, да, спасибо! Я недоразобралась, кто на ком стоял. )))